# Teamviewer will not connect to Ubuntu 13.04 host

Tags: 13.04, ssh, teamviewer

Teamviewer on the Windows 7 machine gets stuck with the "Connecting..." message when trying to connect to my Ubuntu host. I have correctly (to my knowledge) set the --passwd and gotten the daemon running in Ubuntu.

I have to start the daemon remotely as teamviewer by itself throws a wine error. Daemon seems to start just fine. I have direct connection to the host over SSH, but I want teamviewer for a GUI control over it. Can someone give me a bit of guidance? I do not have physical access to the machine (at the moment, but I'd prefer not having to go over there) and want an easy GUI connection. I've heard Teamviewer does not always play well with things running on port 80, does that include web browsers and/or Spotify? I'd prefer those stay open if possible. 
I am running on a dual-monitor display. 7 for 12.04 worked like a charm before I reinstalled Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I was a big fan of teamviewer. However, you got SSH so try using X forwarding on putty.

Check this link.
http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html

Comment: I'm aware of X11, but I'd like to control already-running applications on the machine and not be limited by what I can control. I'd prefer a picture-based system-control program that supports dual-monitors over X11 which does not require port forwarding.

Comment: okay. Does it have to be teamviewer only? If not I would suggest remote desktop on chrome app.

Comment: I'd prefer if there were a way to get Teamviewer working as that is what I have used for years. It seems that it is only this version and after my reinstallation of my OS that I'm having trouble.